# Check if a nuget source is already configured

Tags: powershell, nuget

I want to add a nuget package feed that is hosted on our TFS instance to all of our developer's workstations. The problem that I have is that if the source has already been added, I get an error stating
`The name specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. Please provide a unique name.`

What I want to do is check if a nuget source has already been registered on the machine before I run the code to add the source. Checking the [documentation for nuget.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-sources) I tried to use the `List` operation along with the `Name` and `Source` but I just get the same result as if I just run `nuget sources`

All of these commands:

```
nuget sources list -Source $myURL
nuget sources list -Name $myName
nuget sources
```

Return the same result:

```
Registered Sources:

  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  myPowershellFeed [Enabled]
    https://myURL.myDomain.org
```

I am using Powershell to run these commands and came up with a workaround, but ideally I am hoping there is a nuget.exe command line option that will get this info for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In PowerShell v5, you have access to the `PackageManagement` module.  This includes a NuGet package provider:

```
$nuget = Get-PackageProvider -Name NuGet
```

Alongside this, you can access all your sources:

```
$nuget | Get-PackageSource
```

By default, this will only have `nuget.org`, but with your added source(s), you will see them from the result of this command as well.  As a bonus, because it's a powershell command, it returns objects instead of strings, so you can do the following:

```
Get-PackageSource -Name myPowershellFeed |
    Format-List -Property * -Force
```

---

To address your Q&A:

```
if (-not $(Get-PackageSource -Name myPowershellFeed -ProviderName NuGet -ErrorAction Ignore))
{
    # add the packagesource
```

Comment: Beautiful, that is exactly what I was looking for! A new module to learn about. It looks like I can use the Register-PackageSource instead of fiddling around with nuget.exe as well!

Comment: @BrandonMcClure Yeah, the v5 stuff isn't well-known yet.  The module also include MSU and MSI package providers for those kind of files as well.  Super neat stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the follow line:

```
$nugetHasMyUrlSource =!!(nuget source | ? { $_ -like "*$myUrl"})
```

Or even encapsulate it in a function:

```
function HasNugetSource ($url){
    return !!(nuget source | ? { $_ -like "*$url"});
}
```

Comment: Your double `!` does nothing, FYI.  Unless you're trying to cast to bool in which case.. just cast it to `[bool]`

Comment: This solution was useful to me, but taking into account @MaximilianBurszley 's comment. I used it like this: [bool](nuget source | ? { $_ -like "*$url"})

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple Windows cmd line to add a new nuget source if it hasn't been added before (in this case source name is "test"):

```
nuget sources | findstr test || (nuget sources Add -Name test -Source "https://some-nuget-source")
```

So what it does, it tries to find string "test" in listed nuget sources, if it finds it, it does nothing, otherwise it proceeds with adding a new source.